# Interpret XML using Ruby (Sinatra)

Tags: ruby, xml

I'm building a web interface for a XML-"database" using Sinatra and I need some pointers on how to do this. Sinatra may not be relevant since I guess one would be using a gem to read XML and present it to the user. My goal with this is to provide an user friendly interface for the XML-data. I have no previous experience of dealing with XML.

An example of data from a player looks like [this](http://xml.heroesofnewerth.com/xml_requester.php?f=player_stats&opt=nick&nick%5b%5d=Naw). Can you guys give me some pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the most used library for xml parsing these days is [nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/)

You can install it doing:

```
gem install nokogiri
```

Here's a tutorial on how to [parse an xml document](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/parsing_an_html_xml_document.html) for example.